# How to simplify classifier code

Tags: python, dictionary, classification

I am new to programming but I think there must be a more elegant solution to a piece of an assignment I have due.

I am creating a classifier and some of the data in the rows are strings. In order to process this I am creating dictionaries for each attribute and then, later, calculating the probability of each occurring.

My question is this.

After creating the associated variables a snipet of my code looks like this.

```
            if row[1] in workclass_dict_u:
                    workclass_dict_u[row[1]] += 1
            else:
                workclass_dict_u[row[1]] = 1


            if row[5] in marital_dict_u:
                    marital_dict_u[row[5]] += 1
            else:
                marital_dict_u[row[5]] = 1
```

This repeats several more times and I was wondering if there is a way to write all of this code in less lines. Perhaps there is a concept that we have not covered in class and I am eager to learn about more concise and accurate code.

Thanks for any responses. I know everyone is very busy and if someone could take the time to point me in the right direction Id be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are looking for `defaultdict`.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = defaultdict(int)
>>> dct['foo'] +=1 # no explicit init needed
>>> dct['foo'] +=1
>>> dct['foo']
2
```

that eliminates your need of 'if already in dict / else' clauses.

An alternative would be to use the `.setdefault` method of a standard dict:

> setdefault(...) method of builtins.dict instance
>       D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` method of standard dictionaries

```
if row[1] in workclass_dict_u:
    workclass_dict_u[row[1]] += 1
else:
    workclass_dict_u[row[1]] = 1
```

becomes

```
workclass_dict_u[row[1]] = workclass_dict_u.get(row[1],0)+1
```

You can encapsulate this behaviour in a helper function

```
def incr_dict(d,k,n=1):
    d[k] = d.get(k,0)+n
```

as `d` is a mutable object the function works by its side effect, and returns (implicitly) `None`. (NB `n=1` is a default, optional argument, that is equal to 1 when you call the function with 2 arguments, and has the value you specify (even negative) when you use 3 arguments)

Another possibility is using a [`Counter`](http://pymotw.com/2/collections/counter.html) from the `collections` module, see the examples in the excellent reference above, but for your needs the `incr_dict` function could be the right fit.